# post type => 'any' not applied my custom queries

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, query, meta-query

This is my PHP Code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'orderby_custom_time', 9, 1);
function orderby_custom_time( $query ) {
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'second_key' => array(
            'key' => 'custom_post_time',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    );

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $query->set('orderby', array(
        'second_key' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC',
    ));
    $query->set('meta_key', 'custom_post_time');

    return $query;
}
```

This is how I get the posts but this is the summary code:

```
<?php
    $args = array();
    $args['posts_per_page'] = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    $first_post_ids = get_posts(array(
        'fields'        => 'ids',
        'post_type'     => 'first_type'
    ));

    $second_post_ids    = get_posts(array(
        'fields'        => 'ids',
        'post_type'     => 'second_type'
    ));

    $merged_post_ids = array_merge( $first_post_ids, $second_post_ids );

    $args['post_type'] = 'any';
    $args['post__in'] = $merged_post_ids;

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
    }

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I have a system to order the posts by a custom time the problem that if I set the post type to 'any' and I must do that because I use `array_merge` my function `orderby_custom_time` stop working and if I try to set a post type like 'post' or any custom post type my codes working well without any problem so the problem happens when I only set the post type to 'any' and I don't know what's this is happening.

Thanks in advance and really I hope anyone helps me on this because I waste everyday my time to solve this problem but I can't I feel that the problem from the WordPress.

Comment: Why aren't you just setting `post_type` to `array( 'first_type', 'second_type' )`? And there's nothing in your `orderby_custom_time` filter limiting *which* query to sort that way.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes I tried this before asking the question but by doing this I found that the posts result only from $first_post_ids and posts in $second_post_ids, not appearing (NOTE: This is also solving the problem and my custom quires working by adding the post type in array() but as I describe another problem happens when I do that).